# Bind to Resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have around 15 controls that I have bound the Visibility property of to a bool via a converter. However in the designer they are now constantly hidden, and I don't want them to be. To get around this I am manually changing this between editing and debugging, which is time consuming and annoying to have to do all the time. I was thinking I could define a resource to set the Visibility properties to, and when I'm editing I simply set this to Visible, and before debugging change it to be bound to my bool. Yes I'm still changing something constantly, but this is only 1 thing as opposed to 15 or so.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key=BoolToVisConverter"/>
    <Visibility x:Key="BoundVisibility">Visible</Visibility>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then just before running my program changing it to:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key=BoolToVisConverter"/>
    <Visibility x:Key="BoundVisibility">{Binding MyBool, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}</Visibility>
</Window.Resources>
```

However this doesn't work. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Or does anyone have any other ideas to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: does a window have a design-time DataContext or it is not set?

Comment: Yes it does, to a ViewModel which contains MyBool

Comment: Are you opposed to just setting a `FallbackValue`? Like `{Binding MyBool, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, FallbackValue='Visible'}`

Comment: Didn't know there was such a thing! I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, thanks for the suggestion though, at the least you've made me aware of `FallbackValue`!

Comment: There's also `TargetNullValue` -- but I vaguely remember having this issue in the past (using a bool to visibility converter) and neither did the trick. Worth a shot in case I'm mistaken.

Comment: As you said @bdimag, with a shot, but sadly it didn't work, thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In the page view which creates the VM use this logic:

```
 DataContext = new MainVm() { MyBool = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)};
```

Otherwise you need to provide an object which participates in dependency property system (a `DependencyObject` such as a control or window) reference into your VM and adjust `MyBool` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a solution via coding..

You can define these 3 keys, use "Replace All" Visual Studio feature to change the used key values from VisibilityVisible, to VisibilityHidden for example (make sure you replace in just the document). To prevent the resources being replaced, for convenience, you can define the resource in a separate file.

```
<Visibility x:Key="VisibilityVisible">Visible</Visibility>
<Visibility x:Key="VisibilityHidden">Hidden</Visibility>
<Visibility x:Key="VisibilityCollapse">Collapsed</Visibility>
```